# When $P(H|F,A)\neq P(H|F)$

Tags: probability

Consider a simple example of flipping a coin.

The coin is either fair or biased.

I want to investigate $P$(2nd flip is H|1st is H).

Define the event:

$A$ to be the 1st flip is H.

$H$ to be the 2nd flip is H.

$F$ to be the coin is fair.

Then, by the law of total probability, I can write:

$P(H|A)=P(H|F,A)P(F|A)+P(F|F^c,A)P(F^c|A)$.

I would have $P(F|A),P(F^c|A)$ once I Bayesian update observing the first flip being H.

My questions are:

(1) In these problems, problems often assume independent tosses, thus we obtain:

$P(H|F,A)= P(H|F)$, meaning if we know the coin is fair or bias, the probability of landing on hands will be the initial priors on the particular type of coin. Is there an experiment where this is violated? A pedagogical example would be great.

(2) How do we set operations get this:
$P(H|F,A)= P(H|F)$? Intuitive, it makes sense as how many Heads I have gotten in previous tosses would not impact the unbiasedness or biasedness of my coin and therefore their priors. But I would like to understand via just set operations how we get to the RHS given the assumption the tosses are independent.

(3) Is $P(H|F,A)=P(H|F\cap A)?$
My understanding is they are equivalent as in English, we want to know the probability of landing on Heads given the join event of landing on Heads previously and that coin being fair, thus conditioning on the event that the fair coin lands on Heads in previous toss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the convention that $F^\top$ is the event $F$, and $F^{\bot}$ is the complement, and $\alpha\in\{\bot,\top\}$.

(1) $\mathsf P(H\mid F^\alpha,A)=\mathsf P(H\mid F^\alpha)$ is *indeed* a fact of the experimental setup.   The results of *seperate* flips, when *given* it is the *same* coin, shall be independent.

To have something else, we would need to do something else - some way for preceding trials to influence subsequent even when the bias generator is fixed.   Such as, perhaps, pick from a standard or non-standard decks of cards (remove some hearts, add extra clubs, or such), and draw two cards *without replacement*.

(2) $\mathsf P(A,H\mid F^\alpha)=\mathsf P(A\mid F^\alpha)~\mathsf P(H\mid F^\alpha)$.   If you have a coin with bias $p_\alpha$, then the probability for obtaining two heads on subsequent flips is ${p_\alpha}^2$, which is the product of the probabilities for obtaining a head on each toss.

Then by definition of conditional probability: $\mathsf P(H\mid F^\alpha, A)~{=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(A,H\mid F^\alpha)}{\mathsf P(A\mid F^\alpha)} \\= ~\mathsf P(H\mid F^\alpha)}$.

(3) Yes, the event  lists in probability functions are conjunctive for both sides of the condition seperator.   $\mathsf P(A, B\mid C,D)=\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C\cap D)$.   It is just quicker to type the list format (and the typeset shorter) and some authors will even use the "product" format $\mathsf P(AB\mid CD)$.

Comment: Graham, if I were to try to put my question (2) into a sample space picture, is this correct? We have the whole world, say S. But this world has two states, a fair coin world and a biased coin world. Now, in each state, we have an assignment of probability to the event of Heads and Tails. What I am trying to figure out is whether I can also make this in diagram to form a more intuitive sense, like the pebbles...